# react navigation problem with CreateAppContainer or createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

hello everyone i write some application in react for apply what i have learned before, and i want to use react navigation for manage the screen an vue and my version of react is upper than 3, so i must use createAppContainer for the render but when i actualise the appli i have a header of nav bar but she dont have title. if some one can explaine me my error in this code. thanks

My snack in expo:
https://snack.expo.io/@tadix/textexercicev2

exemple of screen :
https://pasteboard.co/Isg9q3k.png

```js
import {createStackNavigator,createAppContainer} from "react-navigation"

import Search from '../components/Search'

const SearchStackNavgator = createStackNavigator({
  Search:{
    screen:Search,
    navigationOption:{
      title: "Rechercher"
    }
  }
})


const AppsNavigator = createAppContainer(SearchStackNavgator);

export default AppsNavigator
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo, you're missing an 's' after navigationOption. It should look like this:

```
const SearchStackNavgator = createStackNavigator({
  Search:{
    screen:Search,
    navigationOptions:{
      title: "Rechercher"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: oh yes it's true, and now it's work, thank you bro :D